# Comment flag submit button is no longer disabled if another comment was flagged within the last five seconds

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, comment-flags

In the old comment flagging UI (the one before major changes were made to the comment flagging system recently), it used to be that if another comment was flagged within the last five seconds, the submit button would be disabled, and only re-enable itself once the rate limit expired.

However, with the new flagging UI, this feature appears to have been removed: the button is always enabled, and clicking it before the rate limit expires produces an error message.

Can this feature please be added back? I liked that feature because I often flag multiple comments at a time, and the current error message covers up the button, meaning it has to be closed before I can re-click it.

Comment: This is the comment flagging UI that appears on post pages and was updated last August with the CoC rollout?  I'm looking at the old code and I don't see the behavior you're describing.  When you opened the old popup, Submit would be disabled until you picked an option, but there was no timer or logic around the rate limit.  Is it possible a user script was providing this behavior?

Comment: Code around the rate limit would probably be tricky to implement and the UX would be nuanced, but we could do something about that error message by porting it to a [Stacks-based error toast](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices#toast).  That'll at least keep it out from under your cursor.

Comment: @BrianNickel I think the SOUP script was providing that feature; can you please check the old code again and see if it works with that script enabled?

Comment: Yep, the code is at  https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/79b7d852ed1598855abe38b559a5d856f05d0fae/SOUP.user.js#L1361 Same could probably be applied to the new dialog by tweaking the selectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loss of functionality here is from a user script and not something supported on our end. I've updated the status to declined since our team won't be picking this one up.